# SQL: How to get entries with the same month and year as the table's timestamp field?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date, timestamp

I have the following table

```
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------+----------+--------+
| id                                   | app_start           | app_end             | title    | body                        | location | allDay |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------+----------+--------+
| 52e782d7-8da8-4b27-a17e-d6beb72649e8 | 2004-04-27 10:30:00 | 2005-02-18 11:00:00 | 10 years | Something.                  | NY,USA   |      0 |
| a3e11a10-26d3-407d-83b3-c3cd6cda128f | 2004-02-17 10:30:00 | 2004-02-17 11:00:00 | 12 years | Insert random message here  | NY,USA   |      0 |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------------+----------+--------+
```

Here the column `app_start` is of type `timestamp`. If I want to get rows for a specific month and year, say month 2(Feb) of 2004 which would return the second row, what would I insert in the `where` clause?

```sql
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE [????]
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `month` and `year`:

```
select *
from yourtable
where month(app_start) = 2 and year(app_start) = 2004
```